# How to send Headers to the sites using HTPPS in .NET?

Tags: .net, sockets, ssl, https, http-headers

I am using the code below to send headers to the site I specify which works fine with HTTP protocol (port=80) but now I am trying to send to the headers using HTTPS (port=443).

```
        mytcpclient = new TcpClient();
        mytcpclient.Connect(host, port);

        mysocket = mytcpclient.Client;
        SendHeader(mysocket);

    public void SendHeader(Socket mySocket)
    {
        String sBuffer = "";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "GET /"+pathquery+" HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "Host: "+ hostname + "\r\n";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
        sBuffer = sBuffer + "\r\n";
        Byte[] bSendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer);
        mySocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sBuffer).Length, 0);
    }
```

I know there is SSLStream class but I am not sure how to rewrite the code, so it sends headers properly to the sites using SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Webclient class instead of TcpClient. It is made for http... See e.g http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient